# Can't host website from my own PC using WAMP64

Tags: apache, web, hosting

I'm trying to host my own website using Apache with the WAMP x64 installed on my system (Wampserver 3.1.0 x64)

I have a domain which I have pointed at my own IP address.
I have a UPC connectbox with DMZ turned on and port 80 forwarded
I have apache running on port 80 and a virtual host for my domain set up

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.0.157:80>
    ServerName wolfpaw.hu
    ServerAlias www.wolfpaw.hu
    ServerAdmin a@b.c
    DocumentRoot "F:/wamp64/www"
    ErrorLog "logs/errlog.log"
    CustomLog "logs/custlog.log" common
    <Directory  "/">
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
        Allow from 192.168.0.157
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

It's consistently not working. 
The weirdest part for me is that I can't ping `wolfpaw.hu` from the PC where i'm trying to host it from but from an outside PC (at the office) i can ping and tracert it without any problem...

```
C:\Users\...>nslookup wolfpaw.hu

...

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    wolfpaw.hu
Address:  80.99.124.211

C:\Users\...>ping wolfpaw.hu

Pinging wolfpaw.hu [80.99.124.211] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 80.99.124.211: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=55
Reply from 80.99.124.211: bytes=32 time=9ms TTL=55

Ping statistics for 80.99.124.211:
    Packets: Sent = 2, Received = 2, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 9ms, Maximum = 12ms, Average = 10ms

C:\Users\...>tracert wolfpaw.hu

Tracing route to wolfpaw.hu [80.99.124.211]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  mllnc3e4bcb1.fixip.t-online.hu [195.228.188.177]
  2     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  188.36.252.102
  3     2 ms     2 ms     1 ms  81.183.3.142
  4     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  81.183.3.143
  5     9 ms     1 ms     1 ms  81.183.2.141
  6     2 ms     2 ms     2 ms  hu-bud03a-rc1-ae4-0.aorta.net [84.116.137.13]
  7     2 ms     2 ms     2 ms  hu-bud-bp04-ra1-bundle-ether1-2035.aorta.net [84.116.242.65]
  8     2 ms     1 ms     1 ms  catv-89-135-214-54.catv.broadband.hu [89.135.214.54]
  9    10 ms    11 ms     9 ms  catv-80-99-124-211.catv.broadband.hu [80.99.124.211]

Trace complete.
```

I would not be extremely surprised to find out that my router or possibly provider is to blame, but what I'd really like to know is why can I successfully ping my domain from a different PC and not do so from the one I'm hosting it from?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/55611/loopback-to-forwarded-public-ip-address-from-local-network-hairpin-nat

Comment: Thank you @DusanBajic I don't quite understand it, but I'll read it more thuroughly once I'm at home from work.